# C# WPF настройка интерфейса

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток!
Задумал попробовать WPF и уткнулся прям сразу...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это и как это убрать?? даже не знаю как это погуглить)

ну и сам код естественно

```
<Window x:Class="SearchOnBase.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SearchOnBase"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Поиск" Height="657.848" Width="556.301" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Background="White" ShowInTaskbar="False" ShowActivated="False">
<Grid Margin="0,0,2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">


    <TextBox x:Name="textBox_Fam" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="49,69,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="378" BorderBrush="#FFADB4C9" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
        <TextBox.OpacityMask>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBox.OpacityMask>
    </TextBox>
    <Button x:Name="ButtonSearch" Content="Поиск" Margin="0,69,-103.484,2" BorderBrush="#FF6C80B6" Foreground="#FFF3ECEC" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14.667" Grid.Column="4" Background="#FF5366A6" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="93" RenderTransformOrigin="0.521,-0.875" Click="ButtonSearch_Click"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="230" Margin="49,0,-102.484,-232" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="481" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36727482/how-to-remove-the-go-to-live-visual-tree-enable-selection-display-layou

Посмотри там прям твое решение, надо в настройках Visual Studio найти Show runtime tools in application и отключить.

Answer (score 5):

Сервис->Параметры->Отладка->Общие->Показать средства среды выполнения в приложении(Снять галочку)